# Python Percentage-complete calculator

Tags: python, percentage, fractions, factors

EDITZ: I've figured it out. :) All I had to do was add a `.0` to the end of the `100` (and add an `int()` statement as well). :P Yay for float/decimals!

I'm making a factor calculator. It works perfectly. Here's a sample output of the code:

Get factors of {10}

[1, 2, 5, 10]

Get factors of {120}

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 120]

and so on (you input the text within the curly braces ( { } )). It's made in Python 2.7. In order to make it 110% perfect (better than before :P), I want it to display the amount that's been calculated.. while my computer is really quick and can calculate the factors of 120 near instantaneously, if I input a big number like 5000 it takes about 30 seconds to calculate. A little long (This is because it's calculating 25 million equations). It'd be nice if it displayed a percentage finished right at the bottom of the screen so that you would know about how long is left.

So my code (which I'll show you shortly) will output this when you input 5 as the number.

Get factors of 5
   Calculation completed: 20%
   Calculation completed: 40%
   Calculation completed: 60%
   Calculation completed: 80%
   [1, 5]

(I dunno why it doesn't show 100%, I can easily add that in though so don't worry.) Okay, so it's working well. Great! Now I get this one problem..

Get factors of 101

Calculation completed: 0%

Calculation completed: 0%

Calculation completed: 0%

Calculation completed: 0%

Calculation completed: 0%

Calculation completed: 0%

---

Calculation completed: 0%

Calculation completed: 0%

Calculation completed: 0%

[1, 101]

That is quite obviously a problem. It only works if you input a number equal to or less than 100, and sense 100 calculates near-instantly, that's kinda pointless. :P

At this point it's probably a good time to show my code:

```
def getFactors(n):
    out = [1]
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(1, n):
            if (i * j == n):
                out.append(i)
        print "Calculation completed: " + str(100 / n * i ) + "%"
    out.append(n)
    return out

while(0 < 1):
    number = int(raw_input("Get factors of "))
    print getFactors(number)
    print ""
```

Main part to focus on: the first `print` function. :P

Any clues why it doesn't work? Thanks a lot if you can help. :)

Comment: where is number and what is `while(0 < 1)`?

Comment: @Paradic oh boy, I made a mistake :O

Forgot to add that into my code above. I'll fix that. As for the while loop, it's just to go on forever until you close the application/python file. :P

Comment: @Paradic Sorry, I haven't asked a lot of questions yet. And I forgot. ;P Really sorry about that.

Comment: no worries, that info helps though ;)

Comment: `100. / n` to force float calculation

Comment: @Sylvain I'll add that to my code though I'm not sure it'll change anything..

Comment: @Sylvain Oh wait did that fix it? That may be exactly what I'm looking for. :D

Comment: @Sylvain Perfect, it did. :3 Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Glad it helps you. Posted as an answer.

Comment: `from __future__ import division` will fix it for you too

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I took the liberty to add that to my answer ;)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, no worries, will help get prepared for python3 ;)

Comment: Answered in question (edit, first line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Python 2 performs calculation on integer arithmetics if all operands are integers.

```
        print "Calculation completed: " + str(100. / n * i ) + "%"
        #                                        ^
        #                      the "dot" here force calculation
        #                      using floating point values
```

An alternative, as suggested by  Padraic Cunningham is to add this import to your source file:

```
from __future__ import division
```

It makes division in Python 2 behaves like in Python 3 (see [PEP-238](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) for details)

Comment: Egsactly. :3 Ima click that big transparent check mark button right now. :P

Answer (score 2):

When you do `100 / n` it is treating it as two integers, so the resultant will also be an integer.

Force it to be a float by changing that line to the following:

```
str(100.0 / n * i)
```

Having one floating point number in that calculation will cause the result to be a floating point number as well